# Effel: EiffelVision2 changing widget style

Tags: user-interface, eiffel

I'm joining an Eiffel project that has a horribly outdated GUI design. The GUI is built with EiffelVision2 and the application is Windows platform only.

how can I change the look/design of the widgets, like defining shape and color of scrollbars, buttons, window borders and so on?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done using manifest file.

For instance, https://svn.eiffel.com/eiffelstudio/trunk/Src/Eiffel/Ace/ec.exe.manifest allows EiffelStudio to have nicer look than default classic theme.

You can check similar question/answers from http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/eiffel_software/message/8791